# How to encode a String representing URL path with JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, uriencoding

What is the best way to URL-encode a String representing URL path (not request parameter) with JSTL?

```
<c:url value="/user/${user.name}"/>
```

According to [any documentation I find](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0318/#N10532), this should take care of it. But it does not. It encodes parameters beautifully (`<c:url value="/user/${user.name}"><c:param name="section" value="employment 4u so good"/></c:url>`) but I'm not passing any parameters. How can I safely encode a simple URL, like above, without fear of what `${user.name}` could be?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `<c:url>` does not encode the URI as specified in its value, but just URL request parameters which are specified by a nested `<c:param>`. The IBM article which you linked also doesn't tell otherwise. I think that you confused it with "URL rewriting" (which is in essence nothing more than appending the `jsessionid` whenever necessary). The `<c:url>` indeed does that as well when cookies are disabled.

To achieve your requirement, of URI-encoding the path parameters, best is to create a custom EL function which delegates to [`URLEncoder#encode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and alters the outcome conform URI rules.

```
<a href="/user/${util:encodeURI(user.name)}">view profile</a>
```

with

```
public static String encodeURI(String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")
        .replace("+", "%20")
        .replace("%21", "!")
        .replace("%27", "'")
        .replace("%28", "(")
        .replace("%29", ")")
        .replace("%7E", "~");
}
```

In the 2nd part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el/6396886#6396886) you can find a basic kickoff example how to declare and register custom EL functions.

Comment: Thanks, Balus C. This is what I'm currently doing. I hoped there was something built in but if this is the best way then so be it.

Comment: Curiously enough URLEncoder.encode() is actually not the correct way to encode a URL. It is the correct way to encode a URL *parameter.* It changes spaces to + for example. The correct technique is new URI(null, url, null).toASCIIString(), which for example changes spaces to %20.

Comment: The question in your final link seems to have been deleted and is only viewable by 10k+ users.

Comment: @Brant: it's mirrored at http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/01/hidden-features-of-jspservlet.html. There's another example in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el/6396886#6396886

Comment: Sadly I didn't find any library for encoding URL path segments, therefore easiest way is replace(). ...

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you already knew this was an alternative solution, but I decided for my particular use the most elegant solution was to use a request attribute.

So in my servlet:

```
req.setAttribute("myUrl", URLEncoder.encode(myUrl, "UTF-8"));
```

and in my JSP:

```
"...${myUrl}"
```

Comment: This is incorrect. See [EJP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053975/how-to-url-encode-a-string-with-jstl#comment8244110_5064758).

Answer (score 1):

you could use the jakarta String TagLib, which
has a encodeUrl tag:
http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/string-doc/string-1.1.0/index.html#encodeUrl

Follow these steps to configure your web application with this tag library:

1. Copy the tag library descriptor file to the /WEB-INF subdirectory of your web application.
2. Copy the tag library JAR file to the /WEB-INF/lib subdirectory of your web application.
3. Add a  element to your web application deployment descriptor in /WEB-INF/web.xml as said in the above link

To use the tags from this library in your JSP pages, add the following directive at the top of each page:

below is the example of usage in jsp:

```
<a href="str:decodeUrl>${URL}</str:decodeUrl)"/>
```

Comment: There's a big red warning box on top of all Jakarta taglib pages which says *"2010-04-14 - Jakarta Taglibs has been retired."* This isn't just for decoration. You shouldn't use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple in this way:

```
<%= java.net.URLEncoder.encode(request.getAttribute("user.name").toString() , "UTF-8") %>
```

Comment: Well, this is keeping it easy, not simple.

Comment: For me, copy paste in the place that I need it, is simple. Easy could be use less characters.

Comment: This is incorrect. See [EJP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053975/how-to-url-encode-a-string-with-jstl#comment8244110_5064758).

Answer (score 0):

The correct technique is `new URI(null, url, null).toASCIIString()`, which for example changes spaces to `%20`

This could be helpful:

[How to encode a String representing URL path with JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053975/how-to-encode-a-string-representing-url-path-with-jstl#comment8244110_5064758)