# How to display custom currency format using displaytag?

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

i am using struts2, to display data display tag and java. i tried to use

```
 <display:column sortable="false" total="true" property="paidAmount"
                    titleKey="table.title.paidamount" format="{0,Number, #,##,##,##0.00}"
                    style="width:100px;text-align:right;">
                </display:column>
```

but it displays numbers in thousand format.like 2,300,000.00 00. But i need it as 23,00,000.00.
How to do that? I need to use total for that column also.

I used this in disaplytag.properties

```
locale.provider=com.XXX.web.resource.I18nStruts2Adapter
locale.resolver=com.XXX.web.resource.I18nStruts2Adapter
```

to set the locale. Locale displays "en_IN".

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat and can add the conditions how one should format the number like

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
```

here is an example explaining how a number can be formatted in Indian style

[Format Number in Indian Style](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1760.htm)

Comment: not sure about display tag,is there any way to provide custom formatter in display tag?

Comment: AFAIK, DecimalFormat, which is used behind the scenes by displaytag and the JSTL, doesn't support groups of dfferent sizes (2 and 3, in your case). You'll have to write a specific static method for that, and you may then declare this static method as a JSP EL function to use it in JSPs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el