# field:select with a static List in Spring Roo

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Hy everyone.

I have a simple problem here.
in my order class i have OrderStatus field, which is an enum in the database. (Can be "Under process" or Dispatched)

My problem is when im using update.jspx i want a field:select dropdown list, where the admin can change this value.

Because these values can not be read out from database, i was thinking of creating a static arraylist inside order.java like this:

```
public static List<String> StatusList;
static{
  ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
  tmp.add("Under process");
  tmp.add("Dispatched");
  StatusList = Collections.unmodifiableList(tmp);
}


public List<String> getStatusList() {
    return StatusList;
}
```

How can i read out these value using field:select tag, and set them as orderStatus?

```
<field:select field="orderStatus" id="c_photostore_Porder_orderStatus" items="${porders}" itemValue="orderStatusList" path="/porders"/>
```

if i could call a method from update.jspx would be fine also i think, but i know the syntax only in webflow, not in standard roo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the List in a ServletContext or request attribute and access it on the jsp by calling `${application.StatusList}` or `${request.StatusList}`.

you can also apply solution described in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!
For newcomers: 
use it in jspx like this:

```
 items="${applicationScope.StatusList}"
```

implement **servletContextAware** in the class.

Save the list to servletcontext. (setServletContext method)

I couldnt find solution for itemvalue to be working, any way to get field:select without being editable? (So a drop down list, without edit)?