# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, illegalargumentexception, rendered-attribute

I get a really awkward expection, I have no idea what is wrong: I use Glassfish 3.1.2, JSF, EJB and JPA. I have absolutely no idea what is wrong :( I hope you can give me some details

```
[#|2015-11-12T08:52:00.089+0100|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-18190(5);|Error Rendering View[/error.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:415)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1772)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:452)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1554)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:808)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:358)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:311)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:189)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:850)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:747)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1032)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:231)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]

[#|2015-11-12T08:52:00.090+0100|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web._vs.server|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=Thread-12;|ApplicationDispatcher[/aip] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:415)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1772)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:452)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1554)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:808)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:358)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:311)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:189)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:850)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:747)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1032)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:231)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]
```

And my `error.xhtml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="headline">
                Fehler
            </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="subheadline">
                Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten
            </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>Details</h3>
                <div class="container-content">
                    Es ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    #{currentDate}: 
                </div>
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**Update**

Okay, I think I found the problem:

in `layout.xhtml` I had the following line:
    `rendered="#{userSession.hasRole('APPROVER')}"`

And in the View I had the following signatures:

```
public boolean hasRole(RoleType role);

public boolean hasRole(String role);

public boolean hasRole(RoleType... roles);
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the varargs method. Compare to: [Invoke method with varargs in EL throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560508/invoke-a-method-with-varargs-in-el/15561064#15561064)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your error page is not in MCVE flavor. Why do you assume that everyone in the world has the same `layout.xhtml` template in its sandbox project? Why do you assume that presence of e.g. the `<br/>` tag is absolutely necessary to reproduce the problem? Post problematic code in MCVE flavor. [Always](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). Nonetheless, *just* reading class and method names in stack trace should already give a lot of insight as to what exactly happened under the covers. I already added a hint to the title.

Comment: well the strange thing is on my local glassfish I don't get this error. On the remote glassfish the exception occurs. Is there a way to somehow trace down the stacktrace a little bit more?

Comment: Yes, by reading class/method names and providing a MCVE, as already said.