# how to extend jstl fmt tag library

Tags: java, jstl

in jstl currency for matter is using **http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt**.

Tag included as follows:
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

we are using as

```
<fmt:formatNumber maxFractionDigits="0" currencySymbol="$" type="currency" value="${employeeDetail.employee.annualSalary }" />


Now behavior is :

Ex: $470.161 is round to $470.16)
Ex: $470.165 is round to $470.16)
Ex: $470.166 is round to $470.17)

what is expected uis
Ex: $470.161 is round to $470.16)
Ex: $470.165 is round to $470.17)
Ex: $470.166 is round to $470.17)
```

is there is any way we can set round **RoundingMode.HALF_UP** ?

Any way to override the default behavior of [jstl fmt tag library] and giving support of rounding mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the standard `formatNumber` tag to round the number differently?  AFAIK, No.

But you could do one of the following:

- You could change the `value` attribute to an expression that uses a function to round the value first; e.g. [How to call a static method in JSP/EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el)
- You could create a custom Tag that extends the existing Tag class and does the rounding differently.  The snag is:

  - The actual tag class (and its name) depends on the implementation of JSTL you are using.  So your custom Tag class likewise will be tied to a specific JSTL implementation.
  - The existing tag class implementation may not be amenable to extension.