# Calling static methods from ADF

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

How can we access a static method from JSF page in ADF .I don't see that method in the expression builder. Any pointers on how to excess it. TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a static method in JSP/EL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el)

Comment: @XtremeBiker: just added an answer, because e.g. the namespace is declared differently.

Comment: Did the solution Below get your static function callable?

Comment: @L-Ray : Hey , sry for late reply , found another way by creating a public non static getXXX() method and called static method from it. Will try your solution as well and post it  . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just generate an EL Function like described in [How to call a static method in JSP/EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396886/1269441) under paragraph two. It works the same way in JSF. Just the namespace has to be declared like you would with every other NS in JSF (`... xmlns:f="http://example.com/functions" ...`)

Hope it helps...