# How to get static method value in jsp without creation bean in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Below code for bytes to kb conversion code its for Static return type.So how can i get a value in many jsp without creation bean.

```
public static double bytesToKB(int bytes){
  return (double)bytes/1024;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<spring:eval expression="T(com.abc.xyz.YourClassName).bytesToKB(2560)" var="result"></spring:eval>
Spring Eval result: <c:out value="${result }"/>
```