# Issue while calling a static Method in jsp

Tags: jsp, tld

While calling the static method of a Java class from tld , I am facing some issues like while running the jsp file it always display this `${test:concat("java")}` as an output it's not even calling the java class.

**index.jsp File**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="test" uri="/WEB-INF/SubstrDescriptor.tld"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSP Custom Taglib example: Substr function</title>
</head>
${test:concat("java")}
</html>
```

**SubstrDescription.tld**

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>

    <function>
        <name>concat</name>
        <function-class>java4s.Demo</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String doMyStuff( java.lang.String )
        </function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

**Demo.java**

```
package java4s;

public class Demo {

     public static String doMyStuff( String myparam )
        {
         System.out.println(myparam);
           return myparam;
        }

}
```

Comment: Don't edit  your original code otherwise there is no meaning of any answer that address the problem in exiting code. Add edited code just below the actual one and mention EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make few change as mentioned below and check it again.

- Define `<uri>SubstrDescriptor</uri>` in tld.
- Use `<%@ taglib prefix="test" uri="SubstrDescriptor"%>` in JSP.

Please have a look at similar post [How to call a static method in JSP/EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el) that might help you for better understanding.

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="test" uri="SubstrDescriptor"%>
<body>
     ${test:concat("java")}
</body>
```

SubstrDescription.tld:

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>    
    <uri>SubstrDescriptor</uri> 
    <function>
        <name>concat</name>
        <function-class>java4s.Demo</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String doMyStuff( java.lang.String )
        </function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Project structure:

```
WebContent
          |
          |__WEB-INF
          |         |
          |         |__SubstrDescription.tld
          |         |__web.xml
          |
          |__index.jsp
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : damned wrong. Thanks to Braj for putting me in the right direction - will be soon deleted

You should try to allways give it the same name. You wrote

```
<function-signature>java.lang.String doMyStuff( java.lang.String )
        </function-signature>
```

when it should be

```
<function-signature>java.lang.String concat( java.lang.String )
        </function-signature>
```

Comment: Could you please provide further help on this

Comment: There is no need to use actual method name in JSP. you can provide a different name for a method as defiened in tld.

Comment: @Braj My post is effectively damned wrong introducing other errors. Thank you.