# How to pass a EL argument to function in JSP

Tags: jsp

How can I change to correct below code?

```
<%!
    public String renderComment(String comment) {
        return comment.replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;").replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
    }
%>

<c:forEach var="answer" items="${answerList}" varStatus="status">
    <%=renderComment(${answer.cn})%> <!-- This is wrong. -->
    <%=renderComment(answer.cn)%> <!-- This is wrong.-->
    ${renderComment(answer.cn)} <!-- This is wrong, too! How can I do? -->
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It would have to be something like    <%=renderComment((String)(pageContext.getAttribute("answer").cn))%>   But  the field cn might be a problem. What does the getter and setter signatures look like?

Comment: Or maybe something like    <%=renderComment((Answer)(pageContext.getAttribute("answer")).cn)%>

Comment: @rickz This codes does not work.

Comment: What type of objects are in answerList ?

Comment: The type of answerList is List<Map<string, object>>. I did trye (Map)(pageContext.getAttribute("answer")).cn

Comment: For testing, did you try to display something using just El  with no JSTL? What does ${answerList[0]} print?

Comment: only print value ${answer.cn}. It is work well. but I want remove HTML tags and line feed replace to <br /> tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96632/discussion-between--and-rickz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, there is no way.
However, I found a another way.

[How to call a static method in JSP/EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el)

Probably, this way is best.