# Calling static method from JSF page

Tags: jsf-2

I have been checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el) and I am not sure it covers my case. Also, it is almost 6 years old and JSF has evolved a lot since then. My question is simple, I have:

```
public class ReadContext {
    public static String readName() throws NamingException {
    ...
    }
}
```

And I need to call it from my xhtml template as well as from some other random places from different pages. So I would like to do something like:

```
<a href="documents.xhtml">#{ReadContext.readName()}</a>
```

Because they are quite a few pages, I would prefer not to load a Controller in each of them. Is there a more elegant / easier way to do it in the new JSF than the options suggested in the [question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el)?

(Note: I am using TomEE 7)

Comment: The question you found is about JSP, not Facelets.

Comment: It worked!! Many thanks BalusC : )

Comment: Yes - that is what I thought too... Because of EL