# JSP JAVASCRIPT calling static java method

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I need help. I am working on Apache struts 1.2 framework in which as you all know, UIs are in JSPs. Now i need to know from script tag, inside javascript, how can i call static java method.

Comment: AFAIK simply with an `Action`.

Comment: you can do `action` call using ajax .

Comment: see the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el