# Access Database Table using java bean array list

Tags: java, database, jsp

> I am trying access database table data using java bean propety and
>   array list. I to convert array list to html table. I am unable to find
>   any proper example. I don't want to use Servlet.

```
public class ItemBean {
    int item_id;
    String item_name;
    String item_description;
    double item_costpice;
    double item_unitpice;
    public void setItemId(int id){this.item_id=id;}  
    public int getItemId(){return item_id;}  

    public void setItemName(String name){this.item_name=name;}  
    public String getItemName(){return item_name;} 

    public void setItemDesc(String name){this.item_name=name;}  
    public String getItemDesc(){return item_name;} 

    public void setItemCostPrice(double price){this.item_costpice=price;}  
    public double getItemCostPrice(){return item_costpice;} 

    public void setItemUnitPrice(double price){this.item_unitpice=price;}  
    public double getItemUnitPrice(){return item_unitpice;} 

}

package pam.setup;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Item {

    public static ArrayList<ItemBean> ItemList()
    {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList<ItemBean> list=new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
        ItemBean dbitem = new ItemBean();
        try{


            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","");  

                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from items");  
                con.close(); 
                while (rs.next()) {   
                    dbitem.setItemId(rs.getInt("item_id"));
                    dbitem.setItemName(rs.getString("name"));
                    dbitem.setItemDesc(rs.getString("description"));
                    dbitem.setItemCostPrice(rs.getDouble("cost_price"));
                    dbitem.setItemUnitPrice(rs.getDouble("unit_price"));
                    list.add(dbitem);
                }           
        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}

        return list;

    }
}

<jsp:useBean id="items" scope="page" class="pam.setup.Item" type="pam.setup.Item">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${item.itemList}" var="item">
            <tr><td>item.itemId</td><td>item.itemName</td></tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</jsp:useBean>
```

> I have written above code, I want to access database table data in jsp
>   using java bean property and iterate data and generate HTML table. But
>   I am getting mentioned below result instead of actual item id and
>   name.
>
> item.itemId item.itemName

Comment: Nobody will write anything for you unless you tried something yourself first. You will want to write the JSP and then come back if you bump into a problem. I think you don't understand what Stackoverflow was built for.

Comment: This link must help you ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el

Answer (score 0):

New ItemBean must be created for each iteration of the loop:

```
while (rs.next()) { 
    ItemBean dbitem = new ItemBean();
    dbitem.setItemId(rs.getInt("item_id"));
    ...
```

Close the connection *after* the loop.

Use ${} to evaluate bean expression:

```
 <tr><td>item.itemId</td><td>${item.itemName}</td></tr>
```

Comment: I have done this, no change. In  jsp file there is exclamation sign with  fo each loop line of code and mention in tip that unknown  tag c. I thin this may ma be the reason

Comment: for unknown c tag I have added below lines and  jstl.jar file in lib.
 %@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> < %@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>