# How to use a class that is not a ManagedBean in JSF view?

Tags: jsf, el

I have an utility class that is not a ManagedBean, *and* I do **not** want to transform it in a ManagedBean.

In past I read that there's a way to specify classes to be exposed to JSF using `faces-config.xml`, but I don't find it anymore...

Comment: BalusC will probably come by with a duplicate. I know there is one. Closed I could find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el

Comment: @JasperdeVries no, I remember there's was a simpler method using `faces-config.xml`

Comment: You can add any class as a managed bean in the config. But as you mentioned utility class, I expected a bunch of static methods.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Maybe it was a 'trick' of Primefaces?