# UrlEncode the String

Tags: java, jstl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to URL-encode a String with JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053975/how-to-url-encode-a-string-with-jstl)

I am trying to url encode the string..

```
<c:out value="${filter.value.display}"/>
```

I tried this way

```
<%@ taglib prefix="encodeft" uri="http://java.net" %>
```

`<c:out value="${encodeft:URLEncoder.urlEncode(filter.value).display}"/>` And now I got this error as

```
The absolute uri: http://java.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
<c:out value="${filter.urlEncode(filter.value).display}"/>?
```

but I am assuming both that `value` is a property of `filter` and that `urlEncode(String)` is a method of `filter`, as suggested by your code.

Comment: I tried doing this way:-
<%@ taglib prefix="encodeft" uri="http://java.net" %>



`<c:out value="${encodeft:URLEncoder.urlEncode(filter.value).display}"/>` And now I got this error as 
    `The absolute uri: http://java.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application`. Also I have updated the question...

Comment: So you are telling JSTL that there is a function called `encodeft:URLEncoder.urlEncode()` which you have defined in the namespace `http://java.net`. How have you done that?

Comment: I am not sure about that... How can i define function in that.. I thought java.net has some method `URLEncoder.urlEncode` and I just made prefix of that java.net and I am using it... May be I have to define this function somewhere??

Comment: @Raihan Jamal You certainly do. You can't just call arbitrary methods in EL, only the methods that EL knows about.