# In tag <td><a href="....."></a></td> DOUBLE_WHITESPCE in query href

Tags: java, jsp, href, netbeans-7, servlets

I have a very strange problem.

```
    <table border ="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="question" items="${questions}">                                
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        ${question.getQuestion()}                                     
                                    </td>
                                    <td> 
                                        <c:forEach var="answer" items="${question.getAnswers()}">                                                      
                                            <input type="checkbox" name ="user_answer" value="${answer.getAnswer()}">
                                            ${answer.getAnswer()}
                                            <br />
                                        </c:forEach>                                   
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <a href="/TutorWebApp/controller?command=edit_qestion&amp;question=${question}">
                                           Edit 
                                    </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>                  
                        </tbody>
</table>
```

But If I use  in  I get next error 
[image: error_image]

But if I don't use tag `<a>` in `<td>` it's OK. I don't have any ideas.
Thanks

Comment: @TonyEnnis **Bad value "/TutorWebApp/controller?command=edit_qustion= "for attribute "href" on element "a": DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in QUERY.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode your question text (or whole URL) here by calling [URLEncoder#encode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053975/how-to-url-encode-a-string-with-jstl) on how to encode a URL in JSTL.

Alternatively you can try calling [JSTL's escapeXml](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jstl%20escapexml&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CGQQFjAH&url=http://www.javatips.net/blog/2012/01/fn-escapexml-jstl-function&ei=FCamT9u9JtCjrQfzy8H8CQ&usg=AFQjCNFdin5Jn2-SwcMfPnv2_NptWSHspQ&cad=rja) function on your question text.

Comment: JSTL's escapeXml doesn't help in this problem(

Comment: This is an issue with netbeans HTML checker not recognizing the other language inside the href. It pops up the same bogus error for <?= ?> PHP values.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a bug/limitation of your editor. Try deploying your JSP and see if it works as expected or not.

That said, if your question contains characters that must be URL and/or HTML escaped, your HTML code will be invalid. You should use the `c:url` tag to avoid that:

```
<c:url var="editQuestionUrl" value="/TutorWebApp/controller">
    <c:param name="command" value="edit_question"/>
    <c:param name="question" value="${question}"/>
</c:url>
<%-- now the params are url-encoded --%>
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(editQuestionUrl)}">Edit</a>
<%-- now the query string is HTML-escaped --%>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this line

```
<a href="/TutorWebApp/controller?command=edit_qestion&amp;question=${question}">
```

with

```
<a href="/TutorWebApp/controller?command=edit_qestion&amp;question='${question}'">
```

Comment: Now I have a new error **WHITESPACE in QUERY**. Maybe it's better than DOUBLE))