# request.getParameter - unable reading &amp;

Tags: java, spring, servlets, request, getparameter

I have a problem reading a value that contains '&' from the url using java spring.

My summary.jsp file contains the following code:
`

```
<h3>
<fmt:message key="contact.title"/>
<c:if test="${!editMode}">
&nbsp;<label class="eightyfivefont">
<a class="termslink eightyfivefont"
          href="?submitForm=true&amp;
            institutionName=<c:out value="${institution.institutionName}" />&amp;
            repositoryName=<c:out value="${institution.repositoryName}" />&amp;
            editMode=true">
 (edit)</a>
</label>
</c:if>
</h3>
```

`

which produce the following url:

> ...summary.html?submitForm=true&institutionName=r&r&repositoryName=r&r

The problem is when I am trying to fetch the **institutionName** that hold the value "**r&r**".

when fetching the value using the following command:

```
String name = request.getParameter("institutionName");
```

it fetches only the string "r" and not  "r&r".

The string is stored in XML file as `"<institutionName>r&amp;r</institutionName>"` which is parsed and added using:

```
Document doc = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
Element root = doc.addElement("institution");
```

and for reading from the xml:

```
Document doc = DocumentHelper.parseText(xml);
Element root = doc.getRootElement();
```

(I assume the issue isn't with the XML).

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand & is used to divide key-value pairs. If you want to have it as a value, or key, for that matter, you have to urlencode it. For example, like this:

```
encodeURIComponent('&') = "%26"
```

You should be able to use JavaScript for that. Or, of course, some Java method, if the URL is being created in the jsp itself.

Comment: How should I use it and combine it with: `institutionName=<c:out value="${institution.institutionName}" />` ?

Comment: I'd also suggest praki's link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `URLEncoder` to encode the institutionName

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode("r&r", "UTF-8")
```

this outputs the URL-encoded, which is fine as a GET parameter:

```
r%26r
```

Comment: How should I use it and combine it with: `institutionName=<c:out value="${institution.institutionName}" />` ?

Comment: Simplest way I can think of is to set encoded institution.institutionName from your controller.  Better way is to go with what @praki suggested.

Answer (score 0):

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053975/how-to-url-encode-a-string-with-jstl). Create a custom EL function or otherwise you can use scriptlet though it is not recommended.