# JSTL c:url to a file with spaces in its name

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I am trying to link to an image using a `<c:url>` from a jsp but it contains spaces in its file name. This means the url is converted to one with `%20`'s in its name and doesn't find it. Is there anyway to achieve this without renaming every single file to not include spaces?

```
<ul id="abilityTabs" data-tabs="abilityTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#passiveTab"><img id="passiveAbility" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability5}.png"/>" alt="Banner"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#ability1Tab"><img id="ability1" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability1}.png"/>" alt="Banner"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#ability2Tab"><img id="ability2" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability2}.png"/>" alt="Banner"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#ability3Tab"><img id="ability3" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability3}.png"/>" alt="Banner"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#ability4Tab"><img id="ability4" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability4}.png"/>" alt="Banner"></a></li>
```

Edit: I am an idiot, the files are jpg not png for some reason.

Comment: Posted, not sure what else would help

Comment: Check the double quotes. How are you able to put double quotes over and over again without getting an error?! This `src="<c:url value="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability1}.png"/>"` should be something like `src='<c:url value="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability1}.png" />'`; otherwise the enclosed text between double quotes is not what you meant

Comment: @Machina Although it does look strange, I wouldn't expect the nested double quotes to cause a problem in this case. The JSP parser doesn't parse the html, only the JSP. And the HTML parser in the browser would never see the JSP tags. So the 2 contexts won't interfere with each other.

Comment: @Machina I can confirm that this isn't an issue although I will go ahead and change it just for good practice. My jsp is reading it almost correctly.

Comment: The `%20`s should work for filenames with spaces in them. I tested some files with spaces on a locally running tomcat. I suspect something else may be going on. Is `/resources` publicly browsable?

Comment: @Asaph Yes, I am reading other images in a similar fashion on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem was with the file extension and not encoding. But anyways...

Turns out `<c:url>` does not do URL encoding at all (except query string params). See [How to encode a String representing URL path with JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053975/how-to-url-encode-a-string-with-jstl)

You can use [Spring's URL tag](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html) to encode template vars:

```
<spring:url value="/url/path/{variableName}">
   <spring:param name="variableName" value="more than JSTL c:url" />
</spring:url>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string you are generating in the value is already exactly as you want it, why use c:url at all?

What is preventing you from changing this:

```
<img id="passiveAbility" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability5}.png"/>
```

to just this:

```
<img id="passiveAbility" src="/resources/images/abilities/${god.name} - ${god.ability5}.png"/>
```