# How to pass a parameter (that identify the primery key of an object) from the view to a controller using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following doubt about how correctly create a link into a view page that have to be handled by a method defined into a controller class.

So I have the following situation:

Into a view I use a **model** object name

```
<c:forEach items="${scuola.twp1007Progettos}" var="progetto" varStatus="itemProgetto">

    <!-- Visualizza il progetto solo se è un progetto PNSD: -->
    <c:if test="${progetto.flgTipPrg == 'P'}">
        <div class="group-item">
            <a href="visualizzaProspetto">
                <img src="<c:url value="resources/img/icons/projects/PNSD.png" />">
            </a>

            <div>
                <h4><a href="visualizzaProspetto">${progetto.codPro}</a></h4>
                <p>${progetto.twp1009Tipostaprogetto.desTipSta}</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

So, as you can see in the previous code snippet, I have a **progetto** variable that is an instance of a model class named **Twp1007Progetto**. This model class contain some field that I correctly used in the previous code snippet (for example **${progetto.codPro}**).

Ok, untill now I have no problem and I correctly access to the previous property of the **progetto** variable.

In the previous code snippet I also have this link:

```
<a href="visualizzaProspetto">
```

where **visualizzaProspetto** is a resource handled by this method defined into a controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/visualizzaProspetto", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    .....................................................
    .....................................................
    DO SOMETHING
    .....................................................
    .....................................................

    return "prospettoRendicontazione";
}
```

Ok, this is correctly called.

Now my problem is that, when the  link is clicked by the user, I have not to handle the simple **visualizzaProspetto** but I have also to pass a parameter representing the value of the **prgPro** field defined into my **Twp1007Progetto** model object instance (the **${progetto.prgPro}** value) because it is the primary key on the clicked object on the database.

So, what is the best way to do this thing? I know that using Spring I can pass parameter or path variable but I really don't know how correctly handle this situation.

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either with a request parameter:

```xml
<a href="visualizzaProspetto?codPro=${progetto.codPro}">
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/visualizzaProspetto", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(@RequestParam String codPro, Locale locale, Model model) {
    ...
}
```

Or with a path variable:

```xml
<a href="visualizzaProspetto/${progetto.codPro}">
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/visualizzaProspetto/{codPro}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(@PathVariable String codPro, Locale locale, Model model) {
    ...
}
```

---

You may need to [URL encode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5053975/1225328) the `codPro` value, depending on whether it can contain reserved chars.

Comment: Ok tnx, in your opinion what it the best solution for this purpose? The request parameter or the path variable?

Comment: @AndreaNobili It's really up to you, I'm not sure there's a best solution. In this situation, I would probably opt for a request parameter since path variables are usually used with technical identifiers.

Comment: Perfect, tnx so much :-)